# How to modify my constructor in order to accept either a slice or a reference to array or vector

Tags: rust

This is a simplified example of my code:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
enum Data<'a> {
    I32(&'a [i32]),
    F64(&'a [f64]),
}

impl<'a> From<&'a [i32]> for Data<'a> {
    fn from(v: &'a [i32]) -> Data<'a> {
        Data::I32(v)
    }
}

impl<'a> From<&'a [f64]> for Data<'a> {
    fn from(v: &'a [f64]) -> Data<'a> {
        Data::F64(v)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct DataVar<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    data: Data<'a>,
}

impl<'a> DataVar<'a> {
    fn new<T>(name: &'a str, data: T) -> Self
    where
        T: Into<Data<'a>>,
    {
        Self {
            name,
            data: data.into(),
        }
    }
}
```

First of all, considering that I need to cast different `DataVar`s to the same vector, and I would like to avoid using trait objects, do you think my implementation is correct or do you have suggestions for improvement?

Now my main question. I can define new `DataVar`s passing a slice, for instance as follows:

```rust
let x = [1, 2, 3];
let xvar = DataVar::new("x", &x[..]);
```

How can I modify my constructor so that it works not only with a slice, but also with a reference to array or vector? For instance I would like the following to work as well:

```rust
let x = [1, 2, 3];
let xvar = DataVar::new("x", &x);
```

EDIT:

Now I tried implementing the same code using a trait object instead of an enum, but the result is even worse... isn't there really any solution to this?

```rust
trait Data: std::fmt::Debug {}

impl Data for &[i32] {}

impl Data for &[f64] {}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct DataVar<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    data: &'a dyn Data,
}

impl<'a> DataVar<'a> {
    fn new<T>(name: &'a str, data: &'a T) -> Self
    where
        T: Data,
    {
        Self { name, data }
    }
}

let x = [1, 2, 3];
let xvar = DataVar::new("x", &&x[..]);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need a reference instead of a slice? You can create slices from arrays and vectors

Comment: I'm implementing a library, so this is for user convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is IMHO the best solution... so similar to my initial code, I just needed a small fix in the `new` constructor:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
enum Data<'a> {
    I32(&'a [i32]),
    F64(&'a [f64]),
}

impl<'a> From<&'a [i32]> for Data<'a> {
    fn from(data: &'a [i32]) -> Data<'a> {
        Data::I32(data)
    }
}

impl<'a> From<&'a [f64]> for Data<'a> {
    fn from(data: &'a [f64]) -> Data<'a> {
        Data::F64(data)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct DataVar<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    data: Data<'a>,
}

impl<'a> DataVar<'a> {
    fn new<T>(name: &'a str, data: &'a [T]) -> Self
    where
        &'a [T]: Into<Data<'a>>,
    {
        Self {
            name,
            data: data.into(),
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To me, `AsRef` doesn't seem to be the right abstraction for two reasons: first, because it's possible (if unlikely) for a type to implement both `AsRef<[i32]>` and `AsRef<[f64]>`, and it's not clear what should happen in that case; and second, because there's already a built-in language feature ([coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html)) that can turn `Vec<T>` or `&[T; n]` into `&[T]`, and you're not taking advantage of it.

What I'd like is to write a `new` function that looks basically like this:

```
    fn new<T>(name: &'a str, data: &'a [T]) -> Self
    where
        // what goes here?
```

This will automatically work with `&[T; n]`, `&Vec<T>`, `&Cow<T>`, etc. if we can tell the compiler what to do with `T`. It makes sense that you could make a trait that knows how to convert `&'a [Self]` to `Data` and is implemented for `i32` and `f64`, so let's do that:

```
trait Item: Sized {
    fn into_data<'a>(v: &'a [Self]) -> Data<'a>;
}

impl Item for i32 {
    fn into_data<'a>(v: &'a [i32]) -> Data<'a> {
        Data::I32(v)
    }
}

impl Item for f64 {
    fn into_data<'a>(v: &'a [f64]) -> Data<'a> {
        Data::F64(v)
    }
}
```

The trait bound on `new` becomes trivial:

```
impl<'a> DataVar<'a> {
    fn new<T>(name: &'a str, data: &'a [T]) -> Self
    where
        T: Item,
    {
        Self {
            name,
            data: T::into_data(data),
        }
    }
}
```

I find this more readable than the version with `From` and `AsRef`, but if you still want `From`, you can easily add it with a generic `impl`:

```
impl<'a, T> From<&'a [T]> for Data<'a>
where
    T: Item,
{
    fn from(v: &'a [T]) -> Self {
        T::into_data(v)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's by far the cleanest and optimal approach to solve the OP question. Taking advantages of already built-in features of the language it's most of the times the best  way to go

Answer (score 3):

We can use the [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) trait to convert references to arrays or vectors to slices. `AsRef` is a generic trait, so we need to introduce a second type parameter to represent the "intermediate type" (the slice type). After calling `as_ref`, we've got a slice that can be converted to a `Data` using `into`.

```
impl<'a> DataVar<'a> {
    fn new<T, U>(name: &'a str, data: &'a T) -> Self
    where
        T: AsRef<U> + ?Sized,
        U: ?Sized + 'a,
        &'a U: Into<Data<'a>>,
    {
        Self {
            name,
            data: data.as_ref().into(),
        }
    }
}
```

Note however that the `data` parameter is now a reference: this is necessary because the lifetime of the reference returned by `as_ref` is bound by the lifetime of the `self` parameter passed to `as_ref`. If we changed the parameter back to `data: T`, then `data.as_ref()` now implicitly references `data` in order to call `as_ref`, which expects a shared reference to `self` (`&self`). But `data` here is a local parameter, which means that the lifetime of the reference created by this implicit referencing operation is limited to the local function, and so is the reference returned by `data.as_ref()`. This lifetime is shorter than `'a`, so we can't store it in the `DataVar` and return it.

If you need to handle `data` values that are not references in addition to values that are references, this solution cannot support that, unfortunately.

Comment: Wow, this is very close to what I was trying to achieve, and thank you for the clear explanation, but unfortunately the following does not work yet: let x = vec![1, 2, 3]; let xvar = DataVar::new("x", &x);

Comment: Ugh, that's what I had feared from the beginning. Inference works for the array reference because `AsRef<T>` is only implemented on `[T; n]` for *one* particular `T`, which is `[T]`. However, `Vec<T>` implements `AsRef<[T]>` *and* `AsRef<Vec<T>>`; that causes the compiler to give up and you thus need to specify `U` by writing `let xvar = DataVar::new::<_, [i32]>("x", &x);`. I guess that misses the point of providing a convenient API. :(

Comment: So if I understand correctly there's no solution to this, neither writing other `from` methods, or using macros or unsafe code. I guess I would hit the same issue if I used trait objects instead of enum variants, could you please confirm?

Comment: That wouldn't change anything. When you take a generic parameter on a function, that completely disables implicit coercions (such as the coercion of an array to a slice, as seen here), unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually the best solution for my case:

```rust
impl<'a> DataVar<'a> {
    fn new<T, U>(name: &'a str, data: &'a T) -> Self
    where
        T: AsRef<[U]> + ?Sized,
        U: 'a,
        &'a [U]: Into<Data<'a>>,
    {
        Self {
            name,
            data: data.as_ref().into(),
        }
    }
}
```

It works with slices, references to vectors, and references to arrays up to length 32 which implement `AsRef<[T]>` https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html

Thanks @Francis for your hints!

Answer (score 0):

@trentcl your solution is brilliant! Now I see how to leverage coercion.

However I tweaked it a little bit as follows, I will finally use this code unless you see any drawbacks in it, thanks!

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
enum Data<'a> {
    I32(&'a [i32]),
    F64(&'a [f64]),
}

trait IntoData<'a>: Sized {
    fn into_data(&self) -> Data<'a>;
}

impl<'a> IntoData<'a> for &'a [i32] {
    fn into_data(&self) -> Data<'a> {
        Data::I32(&self)
    }
}

impl<'a> IntoData<'a> for &'a [f64] {
    fn into_data(&self) -> Data<'a> {
        Data::F64(&self)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct DataVar<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    data: Data<'a>,
}

impl<'a> DataVar<'a> {
    fn new<T>(name: &'a str, data: &'a [T]) -> Self
    where
        &'a [T]: IntoData<'a>,
    {
        Self {
            name,
            data: data.into_data(),
        }
    }
}
```